# Rewriting http HandlerFunc to gin HandlerFunc

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a middleware written with httpHandler but now I am trying to use gin-gornic and needed to provide an alternative. I have tried rewriting but still not working as I want it to work.

```
func AuthMiddlewarex(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        auth := r.Header.Get("Authorization")

        if auth == "" {
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }

        bearer := "Bearer "
        auth = auth[len(bearer):]

        validate, err := utils.JwtValidate(context.Background(), auth)
        if err != nil || !validate.Valid {
            http.Error(w, "Invalid token", http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        customClaim, _ := validate.Claims.(*utils.JwtCustomClaim)

        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), authString("auth"), customClaim)

        r = r.WithContext(ctx)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

After rewriting it, I am left with this.

```
func AuthMiddlewareq() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        auth := c.Request.Header.Get("Authorization")

        if auth == "" {
            c.Next()
            // next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }

        bearer := "Bearer "
        auth = auth[len(bearer):]

        validate, err := utils.JwtValidate(context.Background(), auth)
        if err != nil || !validate.Valid {
            http.Error(c.Writer, "Invalid token", http.StatusForbidden)
            // http.Error(w, "Invalid token", http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        customClaim, _ := validate.Claims.(*utils.JwtCustomClaim)

        ctx := context.WithValue(c.Request.Context(), authString("auth"), customClaim)
        c.Request = c.Request.WithContext(ctx)

        c.Next()
        // next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "not working": the program panicked; the program returned an error; the response was X but I expected Y; etc. Also by "*still* not working" do you mean it never was working? or did the net/http middleware work and it is only the gin middleware that you can't get to work?